# Spring Boot - @Value("${my.property}") gets resolved to String ${my.property} if missing instead of initialization exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project which loads it's custom properties from `src/main/application.yml`. There it has a property:

```
my:
  property: some-value
```

In my Java code I bind it like that:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration {

   private static final Logger logger = ...

   @Value("${my.property}")
   private String myProperty;

   @Bean
   public MyBean someBeanThatUsesMyProperty() {
      logger.debug("Initializing MyBean with myProperty: {}", myProperty);
      // Actual initialization logic
   }   
}
```

And everything works fine until the property is present. But **if the property is not present I would expect the application start up to fail with some kind of initialization exception, but that's not what actually happens.** What actually happens is that if the property is missing then my instance variable `private String myProperty` gets resolved to a String literal `${my.property}`.

**Can anyone explain why this happens and how can I make the property be required and application start up fail, if it is missing?**

P.S Interesting is that lot's of people in the internet seem to be having problem making the @Value annotated fields not mandatory and they can get their desired behaviour with `@ProperySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true)` but for me it's the other way around. I tried playing with `ignoreResourceNotFound` also, but it acts the same no matter if it's false or true.

Comment: How are things being loaded... Looks like you are doing something wrong then. Also `src/main/application.yml` are you sure??

Comment: src/main/application.yml - 100% sure. About how are things being loaded - I'm not sure what part you would recommend me to check. As far as I know, I have not overridden any Spring Boot logic related to property handling myself.

Comment: That should be `src/main/resources`... And please add your application class.

Comment: Can you check that your yml file is in the source folder path?! It seems like there is nothing wrong with that. Or can you try to use @EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my"). The property is: private String property; then let's see the result?!

Comment: Sorry, seems my 100% was not actually 100%, it is an always has been in src/main/resources. My Application class itself is minimal, but it \@Import's a lot of other Configuration classes, but nothing that seems relevant in that context.
Though this does not answer the question per se, I took a different approach. I'm using \@ConfigurationProperties annotation and convention based fields in pairs with configuration properties. This solves this problem and gives me more control over how I validate my properties and is cleaner solution.